# React App Table Help - Data is not rendering on page correctly

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create an app that takes data from an API, puts it in a table, and paginates the data. I am currently in the beginning stages but I am already running into an issue. The data from the API below is not successfully rendering to the table I created. Below is a snapshot of the code, the only thing that prints are the buttons:

**This.State**

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      err: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      users: [{
        id:'',
        name:'',
        userID:''
      }],
    };
  }
```

**Fetching Data from API**

```
componentDidMount(){
    fetch("https://retoolapi.dev/LlqE3f/data")
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status >= 400) {
          throw new Error("Server responds with error!")
        }
        return res.json()
      })
      .then(
        (result) => {
        this.setState({
          ...this.state,
          isLoaded: true,
        });
      },
      (err) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          err
        });
      }
    )
  }
```

**Rendering Data**

```
renderData = (users) => {
    return(
      <table>
        {users.map((user, index) => (
          <tr key={index}>
            <td>{user.id}</td>
            <td>{user.name}</td>
            <td>{user.userID}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </table>
    );
  };
```

**App.js**

```
render(){
    const {
      err,
      isLoaded,
      users,
    } = this.state;
    if (err) {
      return <div> {err.message} </div>
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
        return <div> Loading... </div>
    } else {
        return (
          <div>
            {this.renderData(users)}
                <button> &lt; </button>
                <button> &lt; </button>
                <button> &gt; </button>
                <button> &gt;&gt; </button>
          </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't set the user's state. When you called the `API` and got users, set them. Change `componentDidMount` to this:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://retoolapi.dev/LlqE3f/data")
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.ok)
          if (res.status >= 400) {
            throw new Error("Server responds with error!");
          }
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(
        (users) => {
          console.log(users);
          this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            users: users,
            isLoaded: true
          });
        },
        (err) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            err
          });
        }
      );
  }
```

[image: Edit exciting-burnell-s8o7m]

Comment: I used your solution and got this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined", the code seems to still have trouble finding the data

Comment: Are you sure that you `API` gives the users? Please add `console.log(result)` in `then` and see what the `API` returns.

Comment: I attempted to see the output of ```console.log(result)``` but there was no outcome, the API (https://retoolapi.dev/LlqE3f/data) has an undefined array of items, is it possible to render this data even though the array is not defined?

Comment: @NewCSDeveloper I updated the code, Please try out it again.

Comment: Wow it works, I can continue on with my project! Thank you for your help.